# Can an Angular 5/1.x hybrid app support HMR?

Tags: angular, hot-module-replacement

The [documented](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-configure-hmr) approach to configuring HMR with an Angular 5 application does not work with hybrid Angular 5/1.x apps.

The core issue is that the `module.hot.accept` handler (defined in [@angularclass/hmr](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-hmr)) attempts to reinitialize the components on the root `ApplicationRef`, but in a hybrid app there are no components on the Angular 5 root (since the top level component is an AngularJS 1.x component).

It seems like the reload logic might work if there were a way to enumerate the Angular 5 components in the app, but I don't see any way to do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the `downgradeModule` strategy, it is possible. [Upgrading for Performance](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade-performance)

You can basically follow [this guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-configure-hmr) to enable HMR, except creating `hmr.ts` and the manipulation of the `main.ts`, as you do not use it in `downgradeModule` strategy.

Much more you activate hmr in the *AngularJs* main module like this:

```
// import all libs you need to boot
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {downgradeModule} from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import {MyAngularSevenModule} from "./my-angular-seven.module";
import {environment} from './environments/environment';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';

// important!: rename angular.module to not conflict with global `module`
import {module as angularModule, element, bootstrap} from 'angular';

// check if in prod mode
if(environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

// bootstrap you new Angular 7 main module
const bootstrapFn = (extraProviders) => {
  const platformRef = platformBrowserDynamic(extraProviders);
  return platformRef.bootstrapModule(MyAngularSevenModule);
};
const downgradedModule = downgradeModule(bootstrapFn);

// check if hmr should be enables and accept it if possible
if(environment.hmr) {
  if(module && module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
  }
}

// construct your AngularJs module
const ngModule = angularModule("app", []);

// important!: manually bootstrap AngularJs
element(() => {
  try {
    bootstrap(document, ['app']);
  } catch(error) {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not entirely sure if it’s of any help for you but I just read an article on Medium about Angular Hot Module Replacement. The author mentions that his method does not require the injection of `ApplicationRef`: https://medium.com/@kubal5003/angular-4-hot-module-reload-explained-e832ea616304